# HTML: Very strange spacing in Strict Mode, what is the cause?

Tags: css, html

The following Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
    <div style="background-color:red;position:relative;display:block;text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
    <img style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:200px;height:200px;"  src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/serbia12-hp.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Has a very strange red border on the bottom, I was not able to figure out why this happnes (both with Chrome and IE).

[image]

If i use an Invalid Doctype like (withouth exclamation markt)

```
<DOCTYPE html>
```

It works?

What is the reason for this? Why is the image not exactly the same width and height as the outer box (200px by 200px). I have tried everything but have no clue why this happens? Is this an hmtl Bug or what am I doing wrong?

Side Note: This is a much mor complicated HTML construct. The example above does not make sense, but it illustrates the problem. So it would be kind if you could explain why this happens.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default line spacing in your browser does not divide evenly into 200. Because an `<img>` displays as `inline` by default, it respects line-spacing. You are seeing the result of this.

Setting the `<img>` to `display: block;` will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It would be very kind and great if your can state some "Terms" i could search for or a link to this topic. I do not yet understand why an inline element with an height of 200px does still respect linespacing... thanks

Comment: Here's a real-world example: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3132/how-to-stop-gmail-from-adding-a-margin-to-your-images/

Comment: @user1145216, it happens because inline elements have to allow space down below for lower-case letters like j, q, p, y, etc. to fit on the same line.  Changing them to block level elements eliminates the need for that extra space.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens (and my guess is that it's on spec) is that images are aligned to the baseline of the text. If you put some text with descenders (the bottom stems of letterforms) you will see it fits perfectly...

http://jsfiddle.net/LvLPE/

An easy fix is to tell the browser to treat the image as a div with `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were bit by the [white-space bug](http://www.42inc.com/~estephen/htmlner/whitespacebugs.html). Two solutions:

1. Remove the white-space around the `img`:

   `<div style="background-color:red;position:relative;display:block;text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;"><img style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:200px;height:200px;"  src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/serbia12-hp.jpg"></div>`
2. Or you can add `font-size: 0;` to your inline style on the `div` wrapper around the `img`

Also, stating `display: block` on a `div` is redundant, you don't need that there.

Comment: Hello creanium, Thanks for your answer. Removing any whitespace, was one of the many things i tried. It did not solve it, problem ist still present, having everything on one single line without any whitespaces... The text-size 0 does also not work (I just thested this). This is avery strange behaviour....

Comment: I just updated the comment, I had the css wrong. I originally wrote `text-size: 0;` when I meant `font-size: 0;` ... I'm always messing that one up.

At any rate, I just tested it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM7HR/) and it does indeed get rid of the red bar at the bottom. If you go to that Fiddle, you could remove the `font-size: 0` and see the red bar come back.

Comment: See @Interrobang's comment about line-spacing. He does a better job of explaining it than I did.

Comment: Hello Creanium, well I just saw his answer. Well you are a gentleman, I will then give him the answered tick, but upvote your generous comment.

Comment: Not a problem. Both solutions result in achieving the same desired output, his just addresses the root problem at hand.

Comment: It's kind of a hacky solution to set font-size to zero.  It skirts the root of the issue as you have acknowledged.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why the fact `img` being inline didn't register with me. Guess my brain is more fried than I realize.